# Mocking StreamReader in C# for unit test

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have code of this format:

```
public void parseFile(string filePath)
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(@filePath))
    {
        //Do something
    }
}
```

I now want to unit test my code, but do not want my unit tests to actually access the file system, as this will make them unreliable if the actual files are not there.

In order to prevent streamreader accessing the file system I would need to mock it. My understanding is that I can only mock a class that implements an interface.

So one solution I can see is the make a wrapper class and interface for `Streamreader`, which I can then mock.

My question is in 2 parts:

1. Is this the only solution to this problem?
2. Would it be correct to add an extra layer to my project in order to facilitate a unit test? If I followed this principle globally I could be adding a lot of extra classes?

Comment: you would need to first pull it out into an interface you can inject here that delegates the work of the stream reader, and then can mock a method call

Comment: Can you extract `Do something` into a function that takes a `TextReader` argument? In that case you can test it using a `StringReader` while `parseFile` passes the constructed `StreamReader`.

Comment: An alternative that could be considered would be using preprocessor directives that, when in a specific mode (say, `DEBUG` defined) you could feed it specific data sets in many different ways.  That directive would probably be before the `using` block, and only enter the `using` block to access the file system when you are NOT in that mode.  One note on this though: You wouldn't be literally testing the FileSystem access section, so that's **missing some test scenarios** as a result.  Keep that in mind.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The issue with the example above is that the `parseFile` method is creating its own instance of the `StreamReader`, so mocking the `StreamReader` wouldn't actually work because:

1. You don't have access to the object.
2. You can only mock `interfaces` or members of classes that are marked as `virtual`.

What you can do instead is create an interface, let's call it `IFileManager` for arguments sake, with a method called `StreamReader`.

```
public interface IFileManager
{
     StreamReader StreamReader(string path);
}
```

Then in your other class (let's call it `Foo`) that contains the `ParseFile` method you posted above:

```
public class Foo 
{
    IFileManager fileManager;

    public Foo(IFileManager fileManager)
    {
        this.fileManager = fileManager;
    }

    public void parseFile(string filePath)
    {
        using (var reader = fileManager.StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can mock the `IFileManager` `interface` and its `StreamReader` method, you can inject this mocked instance into the `Foo` class making it available to the `ParseFile` method to use.

Now your code will depend on an abstraction as opposed to the concrete implementation, we've inverted the dependency which allows us to mock the dependencies and isolate the code we want to actually test.

---

A crude demonstration of creating the mock object

```
public static void Main()
{
    Mock<IFileManager> mockFileManager = new Mock<IFileManager>();
    string fakeFileContents = "Hello world";
    byte[] fakeFileBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(fakeFileContents);

    MemoryStream fakeMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(fakeFileBytes);

    mockFileManager.Setup(fileManager => fileManager.StreamReader(It.IsAny<string>()))
                   .Returns(() => new StreamReader(fakeMemoryStream));

    Foo foo = new Foo(mockFileManager.Object);

    string result = foo.ParseFile("test.txt");

    Console.WriteLine(result);
}

public interface IFileManager
{
    StreamReader StreamReader(string path);
}

public class Foo
{
    IFileManager fileManager;

    public Foo(IFileManager fileManager)
    {
        this.fileManager = fileManager;
    }

    public string ParseFile(string filePath)
    {
        using (var reader = fileManager.StreamReader(filePath))
        {
            return reader.ReadToEnd();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [System.IO.Abstractions](https://github.com/System-IO-Abstractions/System.IO.Abstractions) - this pretty much allows you to mock the System.IO .net namespace for your tests